# Execute beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r) in main thread rather than worker thread

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I want some way that [beforeExecute()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#beforeExecute(java.lang.Thread,%20java.lang.Runnable)) should be executed **on the main thread** before a thread execution everytime:

I have the following ThreadPoolExecutor:

```
public class ContextAwareThreadPool extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

    public ContextAwareThreadPool(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, @NotNull TimeUnit unit, @NotNull BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue, @NotNull ThreadFactory threadFactory, @NotNull RejectedExecutionHandler handler) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue, threadFactory, handler);
    }

    @Override
    protected void beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r) {
        ThreadPoolContextHolder.setDatasourceForThread(t, DBContextHolder.getCurrentDb());
    }

}
```

The biggest problem is that `beforeExecute` is being called in the worker thread and not from the main thread(request thread). **Thus `DBContextHolder` which is a thread local in the `main` thread is not set in the `worker` thread.**

Is there any sort of mechanism that a `beforeExecute` callback **is executed in the `main` thread before the thread is actually executed ?**

The design decision makes no sense to execute this in the worker thread. **What if I want to set certain ThreadLocals in a Map and then retrieve it in the  worker threads ?**

Answer (score 3):

It is not practical to do what you want.

For the `beforeExecute` to be executed on the main thread, the main thread would need to be sitting waiting on a queue of "callback objects".  But that means that the main thread has to be doing nothing else.

The solution is to arrange that the information you need from the main thread's thread locals is copied to the `Runnable` before it is submitted to the executor service.  I've seen an example where they created a class that implemented `Runnable` subclass that did the following:

- In the constructor, capture the state of the thread locals.  (The constructor is executed on the main thread.)
- In the `run()` method copy the captured state to the current (worker) thread's thread locals.

It is not pleasant ... but it works.

---

> The design decision makes no sense to execute this in the worker thread.

Actually, it makes **perfect** sense once you understand what would be involved in actually getting the callback to execute on the main thread.  The Java language / execution model doesn't allow you to (magically) call a method on another thread's call stack.

Comment: Very informative. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @StephenC Sorry to repeat myself, but it isn't clear to me why the `beforeExecute` cannot be executed before the worker thread is actually started. The scheduling of `worker threads` is actually done in the `main thread` right ? (I mean the ExecutorService runs in the `main thread`) So before the `main thread` starts a worker thread why can't it just execute the `beforeExecute` callback ? **It knows the task it is going to run and also the thread that it is going to run on.**

Comment: @Slaw yes something like that, more specifically, I want it to be the same thread which contains the `ExecutorService`.

Comment: @ng.newbie No, the scheduling of worker threads is not done on the main thread. The pool of threads belonging to the `ThreadPoolExecutor` all wait on a `BlockingQueue`. The main thread, or whichever thread you actually scheduled a task with, simply puts the task in the queue (and possibly causes a thread to be started, but only if the number of threads is below the core pool size, or they are below the max pool size _and_ the queue is full).

Comment: @Slaw Ok, so when the `ExecutorService` actually selects a task from the `BlockingQueue` to be run, it knows the thread it is going to run the task on and what task it is going to run. **It has not yet started the worker thread its still in the main thread.** **Then why not just call the `beforeExecute` callback from there and then start the worker thread execution ?**

Comment: @ng Let's say you have a thread pool and there are currently 20 tasks in the queue waiting to be executed. You then schedule a new task from the main thread, causing the queue to grow to 21 tasks. Your new task will only be executed after the 20 tasks in front of it have all been taken from the queue and a pool thread is available. **By the time this happens, your main thread has moved on long, long ago.** In order for you to get a callback on the main thread, said main thread would have had to block until your task was about to be executed by a pool thread. As described in the above answer.

Comment: @Slaw Ok I think the main source of confusion is who is actually doing the selection from the queue to the worker thread. Lets say the blocking queue contains X task. Then how is the next task picked from the `ExecutorService` and given to a thread ? **This is not the main thread correct ?** Then who does the task to thread delegation ?

Comment: In fact, it is the worker threads themselves.  When a worker thread is created, it immediately goes to the executor services queue and tries to take the first task.  If there is one, it runs it.  If not, it blocks ... waiting for one to be added ... by some other thread submitting a new task to the executor.  This is the classic consumer / producer pattern ... where the workers are the consumers and clients of the service are the producers.

Comment: @StephenC Yes now it makes sense. This was a fundamental gap in my understanding. You might want to add this one small detail in the answer or else I will add it in the question. Most people have the naive notion that worker threads are doing nothing until a task has been assigned to them by an external system.

Answer (score 0):

> What if I want to set certain ThreadLocals in a Map and then retrieve it in the worker threads

You can consider wrapping runnable. Then set and clean up `threadlocal` before and after `run` method each time.

```
public class ContextAwareThreadPool extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

    public ContextAwareThreadPool(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue, ThreadFactory threadFactory,  RejectedExecutionHandler handler) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue, threadFactory, handler);
    }

    @Override
    public Future<?> submit(Runnable task) {
        return super.submit(new RunnableWrapper(task, ThreadPoolContextHolder.get()));
    }
    
    // other submit methods...

    static class RunnableWrapper implements Runnable {

        private final Runnable target;
        private final String dataSource;

        public RunnableWrapper(Runnable target, String dataSource) {
            this.dataSource = dataSource;
            this.target = target;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            ThreadPoolContextHolder.set(dataSource);
            target.run();
            ThreadPoolContextHolder.remove();
        }
    }
}

public class ThreadPoolContextHolder {

    static ThreadLocal<String> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static void set(String s) {
        threadLocal.set(s);
    }

    public static String get() {
        return threadLocal.get();
    }

    public static void remove() {
        threadLocal.remove();
    }
}
```